# Configuring use NAT gateway only in specific request url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Condition:
1 Public subnet A in VPC (No private subnet)
Internet gateway is connected to VPC
1 NAT gateway is subnet A
One server instance resides in subnet A.

Question:
Is it possible to use NAT gateway in specific case, otherwise send request without NAT gateway?

Some API interface I'm using are whitelisted and only allow whitelisted IP (I assigned it to NAT gateway).

But regarding traffic cost, I want to use NAT gateway only when request to whitelisted API server.

Example)
1)
https://Some-Whitelisted-API-Server.com/get => Sent via NAT gateway so API server acknowledge it's whitelisted IP as request source

2)
https://AnyOtherRequest.com/get => Sent without NAT gateway -- request source IP is EIP of instance.

Is it possible to configure like above?
I guess I need to use nginx or apache server for url re-routing, but it would be great if above is possible.

Comment: You need to resolve the IPs of the APIs that need a fixed / whitelisted IP and then add a route table entry that only routes requests targeting those IPs through the NAT.

Comment: This obviously only works if the target APIs have fixed / static IPs. If their IPs are dynamic you would need an entirely different approach.

Comment: Regarding case above, easiest way is route all traffic to NAT gateway, abandoning igw, am I right?

Comment: A NAT still needs an IGW if you want to reach the internet.